# Trigger browser pagedown

Tags: javascript, keypress

Is there a way to trigger browser pagedown action with javascript?

```
var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
e.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 34, 0);
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Doesn't seem to work. Keypress is there, but actual scrolling is not happening.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this simulates it in Chrome:

```
window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY+window.innerHeight*.9);
```

Comment: Anything more precise than the .9? I also notice that without it, it "overshoots" but I cant figure out why

Comment: @AakilFernandes Possibly because window.innerHeight includes scroll bar height?

Answer (score -2):

Try it solution

```
window.onkeyup= function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 34) {
      alert('PageDown');        
    }
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hzCFD/4/

Comment: This is not what I need. I need to trigger scroll which happens from pagedown, but without actual keypress on 'pagedown' key.

Comment: Ok, you can observe 'scroll' event, use JQuery: $(window).bind('scroll', function(event) { .. })

Comment: what will trigger the scroll?